# How to validate existence of OneDrive document via its Share link?

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

My C#/UWP app has a section where users can enter links to OneDrive documents and other web resources as reference information. A user can click a button to test a link after they've entered it to make sure it launches as expected. I need to validate that the link target exists before launching the URI and raise an error if the link is not valid before attempting to launch the URI.

It's straight-forward to validate web sites and non-OneDrive web-based docs by creating a HttpWebRequest using the URL and evaluating the response's status value. (See sample code below.)

However, OneDrive document share links seem to have problems with this approach, returning a [405 Method Not Allowed] error. I'm guessing this is because OneDrive share links do lots of forwarding and redirection before they get to the actual document.

```cs
try
{
    // Create the HTTP request
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlString) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Timeout = 5000;    // Set the timeout to 5 seconds -- don't keep the user waiting too long!
    request.Method  = "HEAD";  // Get only the header information -- no need to download page content



    // Get the HTTP response
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        // Get the response status code
        int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

        // Successful request...return true
        if (statusCode >= 100 && statusCode < 400)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Unsuccessful request (server-side errors)...return false
        else // if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode < 600)
        {
            Log.Error( $"URL not valid. Server error. (Status = {statusCode})" );
            return false;
        }
    }
}


// Handle HTTP exceptions
catch (WebException e)
{
    // Get the entire HTTP response from the exception
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;


    // Grab the HTTP status code from the response
    int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;


    // Unsuccessful request (client-side errors)...return false
    if (statusCode >= 400 && statusCode <= 499)
    {
        Log.Error( $"URL not valid. Client error. (Status = {statusCode})" );
        return false;
    }
    else // Unhandled errors
    {
        Log.Error( $"Unhandled status returned for URL. (Status = {e.Status})" );
        return false;
    }
}


// Handle non-HTTP exceptions
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Error( $"Unexpected error. Could not validate URL." );
    return false;
}
```

I can trap the 405 error and launch the URL anyhow using the `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` method. The OneDrive link launches just fine...IF the OneDrive document actually exists.

But if the document doesn't exist, or if the share permissions have been revoked, I end up with a browser page with something like a [404 Not Found] error...exactly what I'm trying to avoid by doing the validation!

***Is there a way to validate OneDrive share links WITHOUT actually launching them in a browser?  Are there other types of links (bit.ly links, perhaps?) that also create problems in the same way? Perhaps a better question: Can I validate ALL web resources in the same way without knowing anything but the URL?***

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid the redirects and get access to an item metadata using a sharing link is to make an [API call to the shares endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online). You'll want to encode your URL as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online#encoding-sharing-urls) and the pass it to the API like:

```
HEAD https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!{encodedurl}
```